# Brick Bracker Game with Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying build a brick breaker game with Java. I've searched many instructions from online to build this. I have a problem here that I can't find the solution online anymore.

When I run my code, it works fine, but when the ball hit the top of the frame, it just go through it and never come back. I want let the ball to hit the top and reflect from it. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. I've wrote three classes. Please let me know anything could be helpful!

This is main class:

```
 package brickBreaker;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame obj = new JFrame();
    Gameplay gamePlay = new Gameplay();
    obj.setBounds(10, 10, 700, 600);
    obj.setTitle("Breakout Ball");
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(gamePlay);
}

}
```

This is Gameplay class:

```
package brickBreaker;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
private boolean play = false;
private int score = 0;

private int totalBricks = 21;

private Timer timer;
private int delay = 8;

private int playerX = 310;

private int ballposX = 120;
private int ballposY = 350;
private int ballXdir = -1;
private int ballYdir = -2;

private MapGenerator map;

public Gameplay() {
    map = new MapGenerator(3, 7);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //background
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(1, 1, 692, 592);
    
    // drawing map
    map.draw((Graphics2D) g);
    
    // scores
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString(""+score, 590, 30);

    
    // borders
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 592);
    g.fillRect(0 , 0, 692, 3);
    g.fillRect(692, 0, 3, 592);
    
    // the paddle
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(playerX, 550, 100, 8);
    
    // the ball
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);
    
    if (ballposY > 570) {
        play = false;
        ballXdir = 0;
        ballYdir = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("Game Over, Scores: ", 190, 300);
        
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Press Enter to Restart ", 230, 350);
    }
    
    if (totalBricks <= 0) {
        play = false;
        ballXdir = 0;
        ballYdir = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("You Won, Scores: ", 190, 300);
        
        g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Press Enter to Restart ", 230, 350);
    }
    
    g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    timer.start();
    if (play) {
        if (new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20).intersects(new Rectangle(playerX, 550, 100, 8))) {
            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
        }
        
        A: for (int i = 0; i <map.map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.map[0].length; j++) {
                if (map.map[i][j] > 0) {
                    int brickX = j * map.brickWidth + 80;
                    int brickY = i * map.brickHeight + 50;
                    int brickWidth = map.brickWidth;
                    int brickHeight = map.brickHeight;
                    
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    Rectangle ballRect = new Rectangle(ballposX, ballposY, 20, 20);
                    Rectangle brickRect = rect;
                    
                    if (ballRect.intersects(brickRect)) {
                        map.setBrickValue(0, i, j);
                        totalBricks--;
                        score += 10;
                        
                        if (ballposX + 19 <= brickRect.x || ballposX + 1 >= brickRect.x + brickRect.width) {
                            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
                        } else {
                            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
                        }
                        
                        break A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        ballposX += ballXdir;
        ballposY += ballYdir;
        if (ballposX < 0) {
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }
        if (ballposY < 0) {
            ballXdir = -ballYdir;
        }
        if (ballposX > 670) {
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }
    }
    
    
    repaint();
    
}
@Override
public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if (playerX >= 600) {
            playerX = 600;
        } else {
            moveRight();
        }
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        if (playerX < 10) {
            playerX = 10;
        } else {
            moveLeft();
        }
    }
    
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        if (!play) {
            play = true;
            ballposX = 120;
            ballposY = 350;
            ballXdir = -1;
            ballYdir = -2;
            playerX = 310;
            score = 0;
            totalBricks = 21;
            map = new MapGenerator (3, 7);
            
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
}
public void moveRight() {
    play = true;
    playerX += 20;
}
public void moveLeft() {
    play = true;
    playerX -= 20;
}

}
```

This is MapGenerator class:

```
package brickBreaker;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class MapGenerator {
public int map[][];
public int brickWidth;
public int brickHeight;
public MapGenerator(int row, int col) {
    map = new int [row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            map[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    
    brickWidth = 540/col;
    brickHeight = 150/row;
}
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] > 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, 
brickHeight);
                
                g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(j * brickWidth + 80, i * brickHeight + 50, brickWidth, 
brickHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
public void setBrickValue(int value, int row, int col) {
    map[row][col] = value;
}
}
```

Comment: what you need to do is implement a boundary on your map and reverse the motion when it reaches the top of the boundary. You could implement this by initiating a repaint at this boundaries. I would suggest using a function to check for these boundaries on every repaint since you are building your own engine

Comment: I thought I already implemented the the top boundary. And how can I use a function to check for the boundaries?

Comment: btw, Thank you for the answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At lines 140-142, you have

```
if (ballposY < 0) {
    ballXdir = -ballYdir;
}
```

You are reversing the `ballXdir` rather than the `ballYdir` when the ball hits the top. Replace with

```
if (ballposY < 0) {
    ballYdir = -ballYdir;
}
```

and it will bounce off the top correctly.